# Retrieve exactly 1 record of each chat XMPP iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on chat module of an application using XMPP Firebase, I have successfully retrieved messages based on `userId` and `one to one messages` (by `senderId` to `receiverid` and vise versa), but now I need to work on Inbox so for that I need to `retrieve` chats based on my `userId` with exactly `1 record` of each friend's chat so that I can populate their names in the `Inbox tableView` to show them recent chats.

**EDIT**

This is how I'm retrieving friend's chat using his ID

```
<iq type="get" id="ak1">
    <retrieve xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive" with="friendid@server.com">
        <set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
            <max>10</max>
            <before>15</before>
        </set>
    </retrieve>
</iq>
```

Comment: can you pls share the swift code of the above query?